# Requirements for NPN, PNP transistors

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, npn, pnp

Is the following a correct understanding of what makes a NPN/PNP transistor turn on or off?

NPN (more common)

- Must have voltage > ~0.7V on base
- Must have (conventional) current flowing into collector (top)

PNP

- Must have zero voltage on base
- Must have (conventional) current flowing into emitter (top)

Are the above two conditions accurate for each? And Are there any other 'requirements' to turn on a NPN/PNP transistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The amount of conventional current (not electron current) entering the base and flowing out through the emitter determines whether an NPN turns on (i.e. how much current passes from the collector to the emitter). For a PNP, it is the amount of conventional current flowing into the emitter and out of the base that determines how much current passes from the emitter to the collector). The base-emitter junction behaves like a diode which is where the typical 0.7V value across the base-emitter comes from.

Note that things like "the voltage on the base" have no meaning for a transistor. The voltage relative to what? Relative to ground? What if neither of the other two pins are at ground? Voltage is relative and the transistor does not know what the voltage is anywhere except **between** two of its pins.

Saying "the voltage at X pin" is like saying "the distance at your house". It doesn't mean anything.

Comment: thanks for this, I would mean like this: http://everycircuit.com/circuit/5229445137563648. Where it says "813mv" around here: https://gyazo.com/43138386ad50901dcc60b2320db09e7b.

Comment: @David542 The simulation is saying that is 813mV measured relative to GND. But since you don't know where GND is (at least if the image you showed me is all there is since I can't access anything else) then it's meaningless with regards to determining transistor behaviour. Typical language when someone says "this node is at 1V" implies "1V relative to GND" and you have to make sure that's what you're actually interested in which you won't be if neither of the two terminals you are interested in are connected to ground.

Comment: you can view the circuit here, I've just made it public: http://everycircuit.com/circuit/5229445137563648

Comment: @David542 I still can't view it because it requires Chrome. But no matter what it is, it doesn't change what I said.

Comment: I see, here's the full circuit then: https://gyazo.com/c425ee9df9394433f60cedc6618bc487

Comment: @David542 It says the base is 813mV, *relative to ground* implicitly. But in this case, emitter is connected to GND so emitter voltage and GND voltage are the same.  So it just so happens that 813mV is also the voltage across the base-emitter, but this won't always be the case. You have to make sure it's actually the voltage across the base-emitter since that's what you're interested in when examining the transistor.

Comment: thanks, so is a better understanding that the base of NPN needs to flow towards positive voltage, but the base of PNP needs to flow towards negative voltage for it to turn on?

Comment: @David542 Whatever you just said didn't make sense. Not that it was wrong, but that it just doesn't make sense. Also, you should not talk about what is happening at just one terminal of transistor. As outlined earlier, it doesn't have any meaning. You should be talking about two terminals relative to each other. The specific terminal also matters. Emitter and collector are not reversible.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I've added a follow-up questions in which I've focused in on NPN.

Comment: @David, if you try to UNDERSTAND the transistor (rather than to use it following a cookbook recipe) look here:https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338670662_Tim_Tom_and_Ben_try_to_unlock_the_secrets_of_the_transistor